# Last non-missing var's index in an array - SAS

Tags: arrays, sas

Is there any way to find the last non-missing var's index in an array?
For eg:

```
data a;
array a(4) a1 - a5;
a1=1 ;a3=2;
run;
```

I want to be able to determine in my code that a3 is the last non-null var.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: This gives the positition withon the range of the last non-missing variable. Loop from the last to the first element of the array, check if it is not missing. Save position and leave loop if it isn't missing.

```
data a;
    array a(*) a1 - a5;
    a1=1 ;a3=2;
    do i=dim(a) to 1 by -1;
        if not missing(a{i}) then do;
            Last_not_missing=i;
            leave;
        end;
    end;
    drop i;
run;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you define your array in reverse order, you can do this using `coalesce` + `whichn`:

```
data a;
array a(5) a5 - a1;
a1=1 ;a3=2;
want = whichn(coalesce(of a[*]), of a[*]);
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this new function to me, this works perfectly fine too, but I chose the solution given by RuneS above, since I dint have to re-define my array that ways.